# How to use np.all to create boolean mask whether each inner numpy array is having dimension of 1?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an array like the following:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array((np.array(([0, 1, 0])),
                np.array(([1, 2, 4], [7, 8, 9])),
                np.array(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12])),
                np.array(([0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0])),
                np.array(([0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0.5, 0.5, 0]))), dtype=object)
```

Now, I want to create a boolean mask to indicate whether each array is uni-dimesnsional.

I tried

```
1.mask = np.all(np.ndim(arr)==1,axis=0)
```

```
2.mask = [np.ndim(sub) == 1 for sub in arr]
```

1st approach is working on outermost level.
2nd approach is fine. But I doubt there isn't any alternative.(Also,I am averse to use for loop or list comprehension in such cases.)

Comment: You have an object array, so it will probably be simpler and just as fast to use list comprehension.

Comment: @jared Thanks for the insights.Let us also see if someone comes up with a good alternative.

Comment: From what I see `arr.ndim` is 1, and `arr.shape` is (5,).  An object dtype array is practically a list.  The element arrays have shapes like (1,3), (2,3) etc (unless your use of `()` indicates structured arrays)